# Django OneToOneField - Insert Record in another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am having the following models. The ItemSettings model has no records inserted initially. I have an HTML table with a link Rules to insert settings data for each item number in the ItemMaster. While adding ItemSettings details. The ItemSettings model will have its own view to edit the details of the settings, once inserted. I don't want the ItemNumber to be displayed as a select dropdown. There can be only one record in the ItemSettings model. I am unable to achieve adding the record in the ItemSettings models with the below code. What am I doing wrong?

Models.py:

```
class ItemMaster(models.Model):
    project_name = models.ForeignKey(ProjectMaster, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, error_messages={
        'unique': "This Item Number Already Exists!"})
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_number

class ItemSettings(models.Model):
    item_number = models.OneToOneField(ItemMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    low_at = models.FloatField(default=0)
    minimum_value = models.FloatField(default=0)
    maximum_value = models.FloatField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item_number)
```

Views.py:

```
    def itemsettings_edit(request, pkey):
    item_master_data = ItemMaster.objects.get(id=pkey)
    item_no = item_master_data.item_number
    form = ItemSettingsForm()
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'masters/edit.html', {'item_no': item_no})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            item_number = request.POST['item_no']
            low_at = request.POST['low_at']
            minimum_value = request.POST['minimum_value']
            maximum_value = request.POST['maximum_value']
            form = ItemSettingsForm(request.POST)
            ItemSettings(item_number=item_number, low_at=low_at, 
minimum_value=minimum_value, maximum_value=maximum_value).save()
            messages.SUCCESS(request, 'Data Saved')
        except Exception as e:
            messages.SUCCESS(request, 'Data Already Added!!!')
    return render(request, 'masters/edit.html', {'item_no': item_no, 'form': form})
```

edit.html:

```
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Item No.</td>
            <td><input name="item_number" readonly type="text" value="{{ item_no }}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Low At</td>
            <td><input name="low_at" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Minimum</td>
            <td><input name="minimum_value" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maximum</td>
            <td><input name="maximum_value" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="card-action">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-small" name="action"
                type="submit">Save
        </button>
        <a class="btn grey darken-3 waves-effect waves-light btn-small"
           href="{% url 'itemMaster_list' %}">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `models.OneToOneField` for this. An example can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField).

Comment: @Tim-Bolhoeve, I have already used models.OneToOneField

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice, please ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe when you get data in this way.

> item_number = request.POST['item_no']

is not get correctly, because when you want to save data with relations model you should save data as instance from model like this way:

```
ItemMaster.objects.get(id=request.POST['item_no'])
```

and pass the result to **ItemSettings.item_number**.

Comment: This change in the views.py: item_number = ItemMaster.objects.get(id=request.POST['item)no']) is triggering the exception error as below and the record is not getting inserted
Error:
'item_no'

Comment: maybe the spiling for name is wrong.. it should be "item_number"

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it correctly, the name for `item_number` field is `item_number` in HTML not <s>`item_no`</s>, so it should be:

```py
item_number = request.POST['item_number'] #This is the right name.
...
...
```

Comment: Getting TypeError -- 'int' object is not callable on this line--ItemSettings(item_number=item_number, low_at=low_at, 
minimum_value=minimum_value, maximum_value=maximum_value).save(). Also getting error as During handling of the above exception (Cannot assign "'123456'": "ItemSettings.item_number" must be a "ItemMaster" instance.), another exception occurred:

Comment: @chlorinelemon Are you adding the record or editing it?

Comment: The ItemSettings model has no records but the ItemMaster has records. So I am inserting new record in the ItemSettings model with the item_number from the ItemMaster model

Comment: @chlorinelemon Can you please also share the urls.py in the question?

Comment: path('itemsettings_edit/<int:pkey>/', views.itemsettings_edit, name='itemsettings_edit'),